# installation issue with Neo4j Desktop Setup 1.5.9 in windows 11

Tags: neo4j

[image: screen capture]

While installing Neo4j Desktop Setup 1.5.9 in windows 11 i have facing this issue. Not able to go thru this step.

[image]
[image]

I have added Path to environ variable. I have added PowerShell path. but still not able to resolve the issue. please guide me to resolve it .
Thank you

[This is log.log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hYT_Ar8xfAzPkTbY86s5TXm84QwbiklK/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the "issue"?

Comment: The problem was Neo4j installation. It struck at the "Choose the path window". The confirm button is not working while clicking

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved
Thanks

Problem was PowerShell. It was not correctly installing